# PHP print to receipt brother printer

Tags: php, sockets, printing, lan, receipt

i'm trying to print to a Brother QL 720 NW lan receipt printer with a static ip address.
I'm trying in this way:

```
$texttoprint = "RECIPT TEXT \n NEXT LINE \n MORE STUFF";
    $texttoprint = stripslashes ( $texttoprint );

    try {
        $fp = pfsockopen ( "10.66.112.35",9100);
        fputs ( $fp, $texttoprint);
        fclose ( $fp );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage (), "\n";
    }
    echo 'Successfully Printed';
```

I got always "Successfully printed" as result, but i'v never had printer working, could you help me?

Off course i've tried to ping from the server the printer and all was successfully...
Hope you'll help me.
Thank you very much

Comment: Are you sure the printer really interpretes random text coming over network as something to print?

Comment: you're maybe right, but this is the code i've found on the net, have you got any alternative idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to implement the same functionality in my application. After searching for hours I am able to find a below library

https://github.com/RamyTalal/Label-Printer

It's seems to be tested with brother QL-720NW printer. You may give it a try.